# Sum function in mysql with inner query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a query like following:

```
    select b.*, SUM(h.points) as points
    from brands b left join
    histories h
    on b.id = h.brandid and h.userId = $userId
    where b.id=$brandId and b.active=1 
    group by b.id
    limit 1
```

I want to sum only points for following cases:

```
where h.type != 10, h.points !=0 and points should be between two dates like this: h.time between '2016-06-01' and '2016-06-31'...
```

I'm thinking this could be done by using a sub-query but I'm not sure how... Can you help me out guys???

The desired output would be:

```
userId  brandId  points 

1         64      155

1         15      100
```

And so on that I have each summed points nicely for each user that has scored those points in between two dates and that the type of points is not != 10;

The table structure is like following:

```
Brands => Histories <= Users
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select b.id, 
sum(case when h.type <> 10 and h.time between '2016-06-01' and '2016-06-31' then h.points 
    else 0 end) as points
from brands b 
left join histories h on b.id = h.brandid and h.userId = $userId
and b.active=1 and b.id=$brandId
group by b.id
```